# nuxtjs/composition-api - Module is undefined on composable file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I'm using `@nuxtjs/composition-api` in my Nuxt application with `Vuetify`. I have a composable file like this:

```
// composables/dialog.js
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-dialog
import { useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export function useDialog () {
  const { $dialog } = useContext() // for some reason $dialog is undefined here
  const { message, error, info, warning, notify } = $dialog

  function showInfo (title, text) {
    return info({ title, text })
  }

  function messageSuccess (text) {
    return message.success(text)
  }

  // ... some other functions with message, error, info, warning

  return {
    $dialog,
    showInfo,
    messageSuccess,
    // ...
  }
}
```

The module `$dialog` is correctly registered in nuxt.config.js: [$dialog docs](https://github.com/yariksav/vuetify-dialog#%EF%B8%8F-usage-with-nuxtjs)

```
{
  modules: [
    // Simple usage
    'vuetify-dialog/nuxt',
    // ... other modules
  ]
}
```

When I access first a page that doesn't use this composable and then navigate to another page that uses the composable, it works fine. However, if I directly open the page that uses the composable, it shows the error `cannot destructure property 'message' of '$dialog' as it is undefined`. It happens in production and local env.

```
import { useDialog } from '~/composables/dialog'

const { showInfo, messageSuccess } = useDialog()
```

Is there any limitation with composable files and `@nuxtjs/composition-api` ?

[Github Issue](https://github.com/yariksav/vuetify-dialog/issues/144)

Comment: Are you using SSR mode? And how are you using composable in your page?

Comment: @ManiMirjavadi yes I'm using SSR mode. See my edit.

Comment: Can you show more context around the usaage of `useDialog()` in the page to reproduce the problem?